# How to stop tkinter frame from shrinking to fit content

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

im attempting to stop a tkinter frame from shrinking to fit content and ive already tried left_frame.propogate(false) and achieved an invalid syntax result, if anyone can help me out that would be great
Here is the code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1280x800")
root.title("  Linc")
root.wm_attributes('-toolwindow', 'True')


#create left and right frames
left_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=700, height=790, bg='grey' )
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

right_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=560, height=790, bg='grey')
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)


#left frame contents
ticket = tk.Label(left_frame, text="Original Image").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


#pullbutton = tk.Button(text="Pull", command=pull)
#pullbutton.pack(side='top')

#label = tk.Label(text="text")
#label.pack()

# Execute Tkinter

root.mainloop()
```

ive already tried left_frame.propogate(false) and achieved an invalid syntax result, if anyone can help me out that would be great.

Comment: Try: `left_frame.grid_propagate(0)` but, if you are receiving a syntax error, then the problem is in how you are writing the line.

Comment: thanks so much, using left_frame.grid_propagate(0) worked for me

Comment: Why not answer your own question?